# Sending http post request to php with many data using angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http, http-post

I would like to send filenames and filepath to php server using angular.
My code looks like:

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'sample.php',
        data: "files=" + $scope.files,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
      });
  };
```

In `$scope.files` are stored the names of my files e.g

> file1.txt,
>
> file2.txt,
>
> file3.txt

and I would like to send another parameter `($scope.source)` where is stored filepath on server e.g

> files/textfiles/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works,

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'sample.php',
    data: { 
             "files": $scope.files,
             "source": 'files/textfiles/'
          },
    transformRequest: function (obj) {
                          var str = [];
                          for (var p in obj)
                              str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                              return str.join("&");
                     },
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
  });
```